# Performance issue drawing on Canvas

Tags: canvas, bitmap, tizen

I have a native game, in which I draw several bitmaps on form's canvas.
The problem is that if I draw background bitmap on whole canvas it slows down drawing process a lot.
I do it in onDraw method of my game form:

```
result GameForm::OnDraw() {
    result r = E_SUCCESS;
    pCanvas->SetBackgroundColor(*backgroundColor);
    pCanvas->Clear(*rect);

    //this increases time of drawing from about 25ms to 50ms
    //  r = pCanvas->DrawBitmap(Rectangle(0, 0, this->GetWidth(), this->GetHeight()), *pBackgroundBitmap);

    //drawing some (up to 60-80) small bitmaps on pCanvas
    pLevel->draw(pCanvas);

    return r;
}
```

I decode Images with  BITMAP_PIXEL_FORMAT_ARGB8888 option.
Is there any way to draw background bitmap more efficiently without using openG?

Answer (score 0):

Drawing your background image every frame will not perform well. Consider the width and height of 1280x1024 your background bit map in 888 format would be 1280*1024*3 = 3932160 bytes ~3.75MB.

I would have 2 canvas, the one underneath would get the background drawn to it once, and the one on top would be cleared and redrawn every frame allowing the background to show through the parts that have not be drawn (transparently.

Here's an HTML5+canvas example http://jsfiddle.net/3jWL3/

JAVASCRIPT

```
var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
var bgctx = bg.getContext("2d");
bgctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
bgctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

var game = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = game.getContext("2d");
window.setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText("" + Date.now(), Math.floor(Math.random() * 200), Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
}, 16);
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="bg" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="game" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
canvas {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answer but I don't know how to display 2 canvases on form. I obtained the form's canvas by calling GetCanvasN() and am using it for drawing. I also tried to add a screen-size Label with background Bitmap, but it only got worse.